# invoke a child process via fork() when using ts-node

Tags: node.js, typescript, child-process, ts-node

I have a typescript project and rather than using `tsc` first, I'm just running via `ts-node` directly.

In my code I need to create a child process with `fork()`.

If I run code like `child_process.fork('ChildProcess.ts')` and `ChildProcess.ts` contains some typescript only constructs (eg: `import {}`, `export`, ...), then the interpreter being `node`, not `ts-node`, will fail.

It may be recommended to use something like `child_process.exec('node ./node_modules/.bin/ts-node ChildProcess.ts)`, but I really want/need the IPC communication channel that gets set up between the parent and child processes when `fork()` specifically is used.

Any ideas on how to achieve this?

Thanks!

Comment: `import` and `export` aren't TypeScript-specific. They're standard JavaScript introduced in ES2015. (Node has experimental, partial support for them now via the `--experimental-modules` runtime flag.) But of course, none of that helps you with true TypeScript-only features that are presumably in the file, like type annotations. :-)

Comment: I'm not sure what the problem is. `fork('ChildProcess.ts')` should run it with ts-node, too. Can you provide a way to replicate the problem?

Comment: Yeah, right, I might have chosen bad examples. So yeah, let's say I'm using annotations, which I am. :-)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As [the reference](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_fork_modulepath_args_options) states, `execArgv` in forked process is inherited from current process:

> execArgv  List of string arguments passed to the executable. Default: process.execArgv.

When entry point runs as:

```
ts-node index.ts
```

`execArgv` defaults to `ts-node` binary:

```
[ '...\\ts-node\\dist\\_bin.js' ]
```

And

```
child_process.fork('ChildProcess.ts')
```

runs with `ts-node` too.

Comment: Ah, you're exactly right. Thanks. I was running into problems because I wrote an initial test for this and use jest to run the tests which is invoked via `node`, not `ts-node`. I lost site of this point. I wrote a quick little driver snippet in typescript and run it via `ts-node` and you are correct. `ts-node` is invoked and the typescript in my child process runs fine. Now to figure out how to write a nice jest test for this. ;-)  Thanks!

Comment: Glad you resolved this quickly. Depending on how you test this, you could possibly assert `execArgv`.

Answer (score 4):

If you omit the file extension when forking the process, it works with `ts-node` during developement, as well as with `tsc` and `node` in production.

In your `app.ts` file:

```
import { fork } from 'child_process';

fork('./longRunningProcess');
```

Then you can have TypeScript constructs in your `longRunningProcess.ts` file.
After transpilation to `app.js` and `longRunningProcess.js`, it will still work when running with regular `node`.

Answer (score 0):

If `ts-node` doesn't handle `fork` itself (which is a bit surprising, but I don't use it), and you need the IPC, I think your choices are:

- Use `tsc` beforehand so you're invoking a JavaScript file, or
- Use `tsc` on-demand to compile the `ChildProcess.ts` file to a `ChildProcess.js` file, and then fork the `ChildProcess.js` file.

Comment: Ah, not pretty, but yeah I hadn't thought of the on demand approach. Something like `tsc.compile(['ChildProcess.ts'], ['--out', 'ChildProcess.js'])` followed by `fork('ChildProcess.js')` may just be the easiest way to get what I need. Lemme think a little more on this. Thanks!